# Datstage Connector Metadata import hangs when choosing any of the available connections

Tags: import, odbc, wizard, datastage

I have a sample job that successfully extracts data from an Oracle database via the ODBC connector and I will mention that I manually added a column description for one of the columns in the Oracle table  (I am also successful in extracting from an SQL Server db). I need to add table definitions, and I am attempting to use Import -> Table Definitions -> Start Connector Import Wizard. I receive a list of connectors to choose from including "ODBC Connector". When I choose it and press Next, it just hangs and eventually times out, displaying not able to connect. This behavior occurs for other connectors as well, i.e. Oracle.
This has worked in the past for us, and it has just started recently with this problem. We have tried using a user with more permissions, to no avail. Please note that the odbc connector is working fine to extract data, just not to import metadata. One of the team members performed a DataStage server restart but the problem persists.

Please advise.

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 0):

The obvious question you must ask, when something is not longer working that used to work, is "what changed"?  (And "nothing" is not the correct answer.)  Have any patches been made, either to InfoSphere Information Server or to the operating system, for example?  Your description has helped to eliminate certain possibilities, such as the Connector Access Service, it remains to do what Sherlock Holmes advised; eliminate the impossible then anything that remains is possible.  Please do examine the logs, especially /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/InfoSphere/logs/server1/SystemOut.log, to determine whether any problem has been logged at the same time as the wizard has been unable to return a list of Connectors.  You might also try to create and use a Connection within the InfoSphere Metadata Asset Manager tool.

Comment: Thanks. A colleague checked and apparently the SecOps guys closed some of our ports (knowingly, or unknowingly - not clear yet). I will update when we know more.,